# Integer.valueOf(char) returning ASCII value

Tags: java

An integer is input as string s. This function checks if the integer is in the given base system. (Assume int base is between 2 and 10.)

```
public static boolean isBase(String s, int base) {
    for (int n=0; n<s.length(); n++) {
        if (Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(n))>=base) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(n))` gives the ASCII value. For example, if s='110', then `s.charAt(0)=1` and `Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(0))=49`. How can I return the integer value 1 instead?

Comment: Your 'this also works' is complete nonsense. It only works if the input is in base 10, which is a bad case of assuming the consequent.

Comment: @EJP Incorrect. num%10 will return the same answer whether num is base 2 or base 10. It is only necessary to check whether each digit of num is valid within the base system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(n))
```

by

```
Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(n))
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String c : s.split("")) {
    if(Integer.valueOf(char) >= base){
        return false;
    }
}
```