# Special characters in a string resource don't show up in Alert Dialog (Android)

Tags: android, android-dialog

A weird one but I've just noticed that special characters don't show in a dialog

E.g the string below defined in xml

`<string name="some_string">A string which has stuff "In Quotation" indeed.</string>`

When used like this in an Alert Dialog

```
val message = resources.getString(R.string.some_string)
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setMessage(message)
   builder.show()
```

Instead of showing up as A string which has stuff "In Quotation" indeed **only on dialogs**

It shows up as A string which has stuff In Quotation indeed. Without the " "

Comment: replace `"` by `&quot;` check this http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html

Comment: And add \ before example `\&quot;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as:

```
<string name="some_string">A string which has stuff \"In Quotation\" indeed.</string>
```

Comment: I don't need to do this for other strings, it seems to be specific to dialogs only

Comment: It's not specific to dialogs. This happens when you set the text by code to any view, if the resource string contains special chars

Answer (score 1):

**Example** of what I would said in comment.

```
String message = getString(R.string.app_name);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message);
builder.show();
```

**XML**

```
<string name="app_name">\&quot;Mes Dépenses\&quot;</string>
```

**Tested on**

[java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7)
Android api 19

**[UPDATE]**

Why for dialog and not for others I think is because the incorporation in the android.

See this [CharSequence](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence)

`A CharSequence is a readable sequence of char values. This interface provides uniform, read-only access to many different kinds of char sequences. A char value represents a character in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) or a surrogate. Refer to Unicode Character Representation for details.`

`XML allows the use of any of the Unicode-defined encodings, and any other encodings whose characters also appear in Unicode. XML also provides a mechanism whereby an XML processor can reliably, without any prior knowledge, determine which encoding is being used.[12] Encodings other than UTF-8 and UTF-16 are not necessarily recognized by every XML parser.`

[AlertDialog setMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog#setMessage(java.lang.CharSequence))

CharSequence is interface so they don't have `toString()` they must use 
`charAt()` or `chars()` depend of api

And a char in Android use ASCII check this [Integer.valueOf(char) returning ASCII value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880806/integer-valueofchar-returning-ascii-value/46880909#46880909)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols

In other word they must skip `"` char because they think is string concat. This is why I think we need add `\`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save others strngs:

```
val message = resources.getString(R.string.some_string)
message = message .replace("\"", "&quot;")
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setMessage(message)
builder.show()
```

If you want to edit in xml:

```
<string name="some_string">A string which has stuff \"In Quotation\" indeed.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fromHtml method from Html class, like this. For API more than 24 you can use method with flag as well like mentioned below.

I have tested with my code and works fine. Hope it helps.

```
var dialogHeader = Html.fromHtml("&ldquo; " + "Awesome title text" + " &rdquo;", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).toString()

AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage(dialogHeader)
        .show()
```

**Note: You can use `Html.fromHtml(string)` as well instead of `Html.fromHtml(string, intFlag)` which I used for my app API >= 24.**